# Scrollable table with fixed header and expandable rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

Is it possible to have a scrollable HTML table with a fixed header like:

http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bhm/7/

But the rows are also able to expand onclick like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pn3m5/

I have been able to replicate each individually, but not both effects in the same table.

I have tried using the following styling methods:

```
<style>
    * {box-sizing: border-box} 
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }
    table, td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    thead {
        display: table; 
        width: 100%
    }
    tbody {
        display: block; 
        max-height: 950px; 
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    td, th {
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-left: none;
    }
</style>
```

On the expandable row table, but it does not yield the desired result. Is this possible (in CSS or JavaScript)?

Comment: I would use bootstrap for this but is just opinion.  Do you have a fiddle with your attempt to merge the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working JS Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pn3m5/1173/)

Had to make a custom script and change the html a bit. To get the sticky headers working, I am using a technique where you have two tables. The first table renders the `thead` and the second table renders the `tbody`.

For the expandable rows, you will now create a `tr` with class `expandable-row` and a sibling `tr` (the next element after the expandable row) with a class of `content` that stores your expandable content:

```
<tr class="expandable-row">
    <td>
      +
    </td>
    <td>Fred</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I tried to preserve the smooth animation for showing/hiding the content, but it wasn't working great. Uncomment the `slideToggle` line to add it back.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".content").hide();

  $('.expandable-row').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next('.content').toggle();
    //$(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
  });

});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.table-header, .table-body tbody {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-header tr,
.table-body tr {
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.table-body {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}

tbody .expandable-row:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click on a row for more info:
<table class="table-header">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<table class="table-body">
  <tr class="expandable-row">
    <td>
      +
    </td>
    <td>Fred</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="expandable-row">
    <td>
      +
    </td>
    <td>Fred</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr><tr class="expandable-row">
    <td>
      +
    </td>
    <td>Fred</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr><tr class="expandable-row">
    <td>
      +
    </td>
    <td>Fred</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr><tr class="expandable-row">
    <td>
      +
    </td>
    <td>Fred</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr><tr class="expandable-row">
    <td>
      +
    </td>
    <td>Fred</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr><tr class="expandable-row">
    <td>
      +
    </td>
    <td>Fred</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr><tr class="expandable-row">
    <td>
      +
    </td>
    <td>Fred</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this in the past by using a series of divs to act as the table column headers positioned above the scrollable table. Using javascript I changed the width of the top (header) div's to match the width of the td in the table below it using an event handler.

The trick was to set the styling of the divs to `display: inline-grid;`